# Remove delete customer option from a user role

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, customer, user-roles

How can I remove delete customer option from a user role ?
Like I have created a user role which has access to manage customers, but I do not want to give delete customer option to that particular user group/role. How can this be achieved? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

To remove delete option from any particular role you can simple put a condition around that option. First find the role of that logged in user.Then put condition according to his role. To find role of a user you can use following code.

```
$user = Mage::getSingleton('admin/session');
$username = $user->getUser()->getUsername();
$role_data = Mage::getModel('admin/user')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('username', $username)->
getFirstItem()->getRole()->getData();
$role_name = $role_data['role_name'];
```

Here $role_name in the role of the user.

```
$role = ''; //Role in which delete option will be hidded

if($role == $role_name) {
 // Do not show the delete option
} else {
//Show the option
}
```